# Unable to install Minecraft Java, error code 0x80131509

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

As said, each time I try to install Minecraft (Java Edition) through the official newest version of the installer on my laptop, it just shows me this error code. I cannot find any information about it online, and Microsoft's helping team didn't help at all.

I already tried reinstalling the installer, I finished all of the possible update of my PC but nothing works.

It always says:

> "Verify that you are connected"
> "Then retry to update. We were unable to update windows. (0x80131509)"

Comment: Can't answer because I don't have enough reputation, so just download minecraft for Windows 7 and install. It will work. cheers

Comment: Using microsoft store upgrade worked!

Answer (score 4):

Open the Microsoft Store and make sure that you are signed in to your Microsoft account. Then, download all upgrades. The problem is not your Windows version but a component of Windows.

Comment: Microsoft store upgrade for Minecraft worked!

Comment: This worked for me. I merely installed two xbox related updates from the store, then it worked.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from: [MS Windows Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/game-pass-for-pc-beta/fc3ace1b-5b8a-47e5-84d7-c95f2332c96a?auth=1)

> Even though you say your Windows is updated to the latest version, if
> you're getting the error 0x80131509 then it's highly likely you aren't
> running the latest Windows 10 build.
>
> The latest build is version 1903 (OS Build 18362.175).  Are you
> running this?  To check, you can either type winver into the Windows
> search box or, hold down the Windows key and tap R on your keyboard.
> In the Run box, type winver and press enter.
>
> If you're not running Windows version 1903 try this:
>
> - Try running Windows update from Windows Settings → Update and Security.
> - If that doesn't work, you can update via the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
>
> Download the Tool and save it somewhere like your Windows Desktop.
> Double click on program to run it. Choose 'Upgrade this PC now' and
> follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: I am running the 21h1 version (OS build 19043.1320), and even after trying to update with the method you proposed, my PC stays in 21h1. Do you have any other way i could avoice the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Mojang's Official Support Twitter has made a [post](https://twitter.com/MojangStatus/status/1455550308088754180) (or rather retweeted one by their status account) about issues with Java users that own Game Pass not being able to use the game:

> We’re aware that Game Pass members cannot yet access Minecraft Java Edition! We’re working on getting a resolution in place and will update soon.

From what I've researched, they released a [new launcher](https://twitter.com/SomeKindaELF/status/1455707193689493512) and it seems to have some issues on their end.  You will have to wait for them to release a fix unfortunately.  The Mojang Status account made a [post](https://twitter.com/MojangStatus/status/1455625487246561282) saying it should be fixed, but it does not appear to be for a number of users (see twitter replies chain).

Answer (score 1):

For those of whom updating Windows didn't work, download Minecraft for Windows 7. That will run.

Comment: How does one do this? Is this even an option considering Windows 7 is EOLed?

Comment: Windows 10 is doing some extra checks which are failing. Technically there wouldn't be much difference between the both (windows 7 and 10).

Comment: The Minecraft website doesn't make this an easy link to find, guiding you somewere else where it isn't listed, but the page with the Windows 7 MSI installer is here: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download  (Using this is what eventually worked for me, after upgrading everything and failing.)